# Custom validation with conditional fields

Tags: forms

I have a content_type campusactiviteit which has a lot of conditional fields.

When the user hits "catering" three fields appear: "*kostenplaats*", "*bestelbonnummer*" and "*soort_catering*".

When the user hits "*soort_catering*", three other conditional fields appear.

But, "*kostenplaats*" OR "*bestelbonnummer*" are required. Herefore I wrote a custom validation. This works, but the conditional fields of "*soort_catering*" don't work anymore.

This is my custom validation:

```
function kostenplaats_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) { 
  switch ($form_id) { 
    case 'campusactiviteit_node_form':
      $form['#validate'][] = 'custom_data_validate';
      break;
    }
}

function custom_data_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $values = $form_state['values'];

  if(!empty($values['field_catering'][und][0]['value'])){
    if (empty($values['field_op_welke_kostenplaats_mag_'][und][0]['value']) && empty($values['field_bestelbonnummer_ku_leuven'][und][0]['value'])) {
        form_set_error('field_op_welke_kostenplaats_mag_');
        form_set_error('field_bestelbonnummer_ku_leuven');
        drupal_set_message(t('U moet ofwel een bestelbonnummer of de kostenplaats invullen!'));
      }
  }
}
```

Is there a solution for this or another way to solve this?

Comment: It's how I also do it. And I also implement a submit handler wherein I clear all values that could have been set by the user who then changed his mind, which results in the hidden fields which should be empty that are now populated and written to the database.

Comment: And you might want to check the order the submit handlers are added in so yours go first. If not possible move that code to the validation handler.